# Page Reloads Even After event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, http, fetch-api, reload

I've been working on this piece of code meant for a login screen. When the form submits, I don't want the page to reload as it clears the error box meant to show up. I've been pulling my hair out over why the page reloads. It shouldn't reload when the error.preventDefault() is called right?

Here is my html code. The inputs aren't in a form and the button is a general submit button that has an event listener for a click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../styles/signUp.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="nav">
        <div id="logo">Studentship</div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-section">
          <h2>For students...</h2>

          <div id="Serror-message""></div>

          <div id="inputContainer">
            <input type="text" id="Susername" name="username" placeholder="Username (What People See)" required>
            <input type="password" id="Spassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="number" id="Sgrade" name="grade" min=1 max=12 placeholder="Grade" required>
            <input type="number" id="Szipcode" name="zipcode" min=00501 max=99950 placeholder="Zip-Code" required>

            <button id="Ssubmit">Join</button>
          </div>

        </div>


        <div class="right-section">
          <h2>For companies...</h2>

          <div id="Cerror-message" style="display: none;"></div>

          <div id="inputContainer">
            <input type="text" id="Cname" name="name" placeholder="Official Company Name" required>
            <input type="password" id="Cpassword" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
            <input type="number" id="Czipcode" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip-Code" required>
            <!-- TODO: Add Categories for Industries -->
            <label for="Industry">Industry</label>
            <select id="Cindustry" name="Industry">
                <option value="Research">Research</option>
                <option value="Tutoring">Tutoring</option>
            </select>

            <button id="Csubmit">Join</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    
</body>

<script src="../../scripts/signUp.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
Here is my javascript code.
// Praneeth O - 03/06/2023

// Code for Student 
const studentButton = document.getElementById('Ssubmit');
const studErrorBox = document.getElementById('Serror-message');

studentButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  var formData = {
    username: document.getElementById("Susername").value,
    password: document.getElementById("Spassword").value,
    grade: document.getElementById("Sgrade").value,
    zip: document.getElementById("Szipcode").value,
    role: true,
    industry: "null"
  }
  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/users'; // Replace with your API endpoint URL

  try {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.status === 201) {
          console.log("User Created Successfully");
          window.location.href = "../dashboard.html";
        } else if(response.status === 409) {
          studErrorBox.innerHTML = "Username already exists :)";
        } else if(response.status === 401) {
          studErrorBox.innerHTML = "Make sure to enter all of your indo!"
        } else {
          throw new Error("Something Went Wrong");
        }

        studentButton.disabled = true;
      });
  }
  catch (error) {
    studErrorBox.innerHTML = "Something went wrong. Contact us with details!";
  }
})
```

Any help is appreciated a lot!

Thanks in advance

I tried everything from including a form and setting the event to submit, but the page reloads regardless. The error box shows up for .2 seconds then disappears.

Comment: Is this your final code. I don't see any issue in here, it must be somewhere else. Also it is not error.preventDefault(), it is event.preventDefault()

Comment: Yeah this is the code I have running on visual. I also have event.preventDefault() in my code. I think it might be a problem with my live server but I have 0 idea